# Using token_ids directly for response_template in DataCollatorForLM (not working)?

Tags: python, pytorch, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I'm trying to use DataCollatorForCompletionOnlyLM in my SFT script. I'm using LLAMA2 as a base model and therefore I'm running into the same problem that is mentioned in the [SFT write-up from HF](https://huggingface.co/docs/trl/main/en/sft_trainer). I've tried the proposed fix in the write-up, which is to encode the contextualized response key and then pass that directly in to the collator, however, I run into the following error:

`ValueError: TextEncodeInput must be Union[TextInputSequence, Tuple[InputSequence, InputSequence]]]`

Here is what I'm trying:

```
response_template_with_context="\n### Response:"
response_template_ids = tokenizer.encode(response_template_with_context, add_special_tokens=False)
data_collator = DataCollatorForCompletionOnlyLM(response_template=response_template_ids, tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False, return_tensors="pt", pad_to_multiple_of=8)
```

and then configure my `TrainingArguments` and `SFTTrainer`

```
trainer = SFTTrainer(
    model=model,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=test_dataset,
    peft_config=peft_config,
    max_seq_length=script_args.seq_length,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    dataset_text_field="text",
    packing=False,
    data_collator=data_collator,
    # formatting_func=format_samples,
    args=args,
)
```

and run `trainer.train()` which yields the error. Any idea how I might be able to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I hit the same issue. With a bit of searching in the library, I found that the `response_template` argument in the `DataCollatorForCompletionOnlyLM` is expected to be of **string type**.

Thus, using the correct response template in this line of code should not through any error.

`data_collator = DataCollatorForCompletionOnlyLM(response_template=**response_template_with_context**, tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False, return_tensors="pt", pad_to_multiple_of=8)`

I believe this should work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
response_template_ids = tokenizer.encode(f"\n{response_template_with_context}", add_special_tokens=False)[2:]
data_collator = DataCollatorForCompletionOnlyLM(response_template=response_template_ids, tokenizer=tokenizer, mlm=False, return_tensors="pt", pad_to_multiple_of=8)
```